# No access of model inside the template

Tags: ember.js

I have a post route `post.index` inside the route,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    this.get('store').findAll('post');
  }
});
```

Inside the post hbs,

```
{{debugger}}
<ul>
{{#each model as |post|}}
  {{post/post-item
    post=post
  }}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

However, when I inspect the context using debugger I see `null` for model.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should return the result.

```
model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('post');
  }
```

Comment: No wonder I only see it inside the store. Thanks @kumkanillam